# Session variable problems c#

Tags: c#, asp.net

I have a session variable that is composed by an object that is composed by a list of strings
how can I retrieve it´s value? 
i know that this is possible

```
 List<string>Session["data"]
```

but how do I cast session variable if it is an object of lists?

Comment: `Session["data"] as List<string>`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If what you want to retrieve is a list of strings:

```
List<String> data = (List<String>) Session["data"];
```

If what you mean is that you have an Object that contains a list of strings:

```
ObjectWithListOfStrings data = (ObjectWithListOfStrings)Session["data"];
List<String> retrievedData = data.listOfStringsArray;
```

Answer (score 4):

```
var list = Session["data"] as List<string>;
```

Answer (score 0):

```
var myList =  Session["data"] as List<string>;
```

or

```
var myList = (List<string>)Session["data"];
```

Comment: Then don't submit an incomplete answer.

Comment: indeed it was a complete one, only thing was formating

Comment: Not at all, what you posted wasn't just wrong, it wouldn't even compile.

Comment: bad day for me, everywhere i post am getting downvotes :)

Comment: Well, if you post bad answers, eventually you get called out on [meta](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/345182/how-to-deal-with-fast-but-bad-answerers)

Comment: i got the reason now, i will not be able to post any answers more

Comment: Do you think you would have gotten downvotes if you had posted good quality answers?

Comment: @DavidG Definitely am targeted in that thread, i usually post answers fast for #angular tags but certainly they are not bad. here its not a bad answer at all. i have posted the same answer, but i donno!

Comment: But I'm asking if you had posted a good quality, *correct* answer as the first post instead of submitting what was essentially nonsense, do you think you would have been downvoted?

Comment: Note that the only reason I remembered it was you being discussed on meta was because I saw a 30k+ user post an answer that was terrible and not well thought out at all.

Comment: i was answering from mobile, i will make sure not to post an incomplete answer from here on!  thanks for explaining more ! cheers